# Scrape zoho-analitics externally stored table. Is it possible?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a zoho-analytics table from this webpage for a project at the university. For the moment I have no ideas. I can't see the values in the inspect, and therefore I cannot use Beautifulsoup in Python (my favourite one).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pGTd.png)

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks a lot,

Joseph

Comment: The values as in A in different colors? Those are Images not text.

Comment: What values are you looking for?

Comment: the ones below, under the text "Explore the full 2020 scores", that is the table I want to extract. It has more than 6000 rows

Comment: Hey did you somehow get the data?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with BeautifulSoup, seems like you can't soup these values that are inside the table because they are not on the website but stored externally(?)

EDIT:

https://analytics.zoho.com/open-view/938032000481034014

This is the link the table and its data are stored.

So I tried scraping from it with bs4 and it works.
The class of the rows is `"zdbDataRowDiv"`
Try:

```py
container = page_soup.findAll("div","class":"zdbDataRowDiv")
```

Code explanation:

```py
container   # the variable where your data is stored, name it how you like
page_soup   # your html page you souped with BeautifulSoup
findAll("tag",{"attribute":"value"})   # this function finds every tag which has the specific value inside its attribute
```

Comment: thanks a lot... could you be a little more specific on the code you used? thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of your link you previously used use my link. There you can scrape with bs4 like usual.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored within the `<script>` tags in json format. Just a matter of pulling those out and parsing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json


url = 'https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/4540617/embed'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    if 'var _Flourish_data_column_names = ' in script.text:
        json_str = script.text
        
        col_names = json_str.split('var _Flourish_data_column_names = ')[-1].split(',\n')[0]
        cols = json.loads(col_names)
        data = json_str.split('_Flourish_data = ')[-1].split(',\n')[0]
    
        loop=True
        while loop == True:
            try:
                jsonData = json.loads(data)
                loop = False
                break
            except:
                data = data.rsplit(';',1)[0]
    
rows = []
headers = cols['rows']['columns']
for row in jsonData['rows']:
    rows.append(row['columns'])
    
    
table = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=headers)
for col in headers[1:]:
    table.loc[table[col] != '', col] = 'A'
```

**Output:**

```
print (table)

                           Company Climate change Forests Water security
0                           Danone              A       A              A
1                     FIRMENICH SA              A       A              A
2           FUJI OIL HOLDINGS INC.              A       A              A
3                           HP Inc              A       A              A
4                  KAO Corporation              A       A              A
..                             ...            ...     ...            ...
308             Woolworths Limited              A                       
309                Workspace Group              A                       
310  Yokogawa Electric Corporation              A                      A
311      Yuanta Financial Holdings              A                       
312                     Zalando SE              A                       

[313 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: thanks but that was not the table. I mean the one on the bottom (please check the picture)